# Finding fuse bulb when multiple bulbs are connected in series

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current

Ten bulbs are connected in series. one of them is faulty.  check which bulb is faulty with a battery and connectors to connect . What will be  minimum number of times one will have to connect the series bulb connection to the battery to find the faulty bulb considering all possible cases.